# Can't switch between proto and implement in C++ project

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

I have use `semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle` to switch between the function's proto and impl, but when I use this feature it always doesn't do anything except saying that it can't find correspongding implement, the other feature like name completion is OK.Can anyone help me on this issue? And I really eager to know whether the semantic only parse the current buffer and the header files in include path, not parsing other implement files. I mean that whether semantic parses all the file in the project when it try to find the implement of a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proto/impl toggle will look for symbols in all the files of your project that have been parsed so far.  It runs into trouble when the sources don't have the right includes and you try to jump between methods.  There is an explanation, with a hacky work-around patch on the mailing list here:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=4FDBF890.8010505%40siege-engine.com&forum_name=cedet-devel

Comment: Thank you Eric, I have found that cedet will parse the buffer you have opened right now, but the other files in the project in idle time. So cedet need some time to finish parsing all the files in the project, then the semantic-analyze-proto-impl-toggle can work rightly.